# Minipages in macros for ConTeXt

Tags: context, minipage, arabic

In LaTex I build the following macro "kum" for translating arabic to german. The result are two minipages, left one with german, right one with arabic (the other two minipages were for design-issues). The macro "arab" is not shown, it just choose an arabic font.

```
\newcommand{\kum}[2]{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.445\textwidth} \small
#1
\end{minipage} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.05\textwidth} 
 ~
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.445\textwidth} 
\begin{arab}[voc]
\raggedleft
#2
\end{arab}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.06\textwidth} 
~
\end{minipage}
}
```

Now I've two questions:

1. What is the equivalent of minipages in ConTeXt?
2. How to realize the above LaTeX code in ConTeXt? (both with engine LuaTeX)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [paragraphs](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/defineparagraphs) mechanism (see also manual section 4.10 “Paragraphs in columns”). Here is an example:

```
\defineparagraphs
  [Translation]
  [n=3,
   distance=2em]

\setupparagraphs
  [Translation] [1]
  [width=.4\textwidth,
   style=small]

\setupparagraphs
  [Translation] [2]
  [width=.6\textwidth,
   align=flushleft]

\starttext
  \startTranslation
    \input knuth
    \Translation
    \input tufte
  \stopTranslation
\stoptext
```

result

[image: result]