# Width-per-column not working in ConTeXt columnset

Tags: context, two-column, context-mkiv

I'm trying to put some information and a table (`\starttabulate`...`\stoptabulate`) aside to a image, the image in the left column and the title and the table in the right column. So what I did is this:

```
\definecolumnset[doscolumnas][n=2]
\setupcolumnset[doscolumnas][1][width=.2\makeupwidth]

\startcolumnset[doscolumnas]
\externalfigure[programacion-semanal][width=.15\makeupwidth]
\column
{\bfd Programación semanal}\par

\starttabulate[|j1r|j1r|j2r|l|]
\NC  1 \NC 15 \NC  2 \NC Academia \NC \NR
\NC  4 \NC 11 \NC 15 \NC Cultura \NC \NR
\stoptabulate
```

\stopcolumnset

But both columns still appear with the same width size! I'm using the very latest version of ConTeXt, but I don't know if is this something I did wrong (I was following the Columns documentation at http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/columns.pdf). Can anyone give me a clue about this? Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a bug in the current version. Depending on you needs the [paragraphs mechanism](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77701/5245) might be an alternative.

Comment: @Marco It worked very smooth! Thank you so much for your suggestion.