# ConTeXt: Prevent page break between heading and image

Tags: page-breaking, context, context-mkiv

Using ConteXt, how could one prevent a page break between a heading and an image or text + image? For example, given:

```
 \section{With a Chart}
 \placefigure[here] {}{\externalfigure[Chart.pdf]}

 % or

 \section{With a Chart}
 \placefigure[right] {}{\externalfigure[Chart.pdf][width=5cm]}
 Hello, world ...
```

The above sequences regularly result in a page break between the section heading.

I noticed a couple [related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133043) questions, but nothing exactly on this - what I would think as a trivial situation that might have a more straightforward answer than I have seen in the other questions.

Comment: I generally use \rule{0pt}{\testlen}\vspace{-\testlen}\newline\vspace{-\baselineskip} to force a page break unless there is \testlen left on the page.

Comment: Hi @JohnKormylo - I want to prevent a page break, not force one. :)

Comment: By forcing a page break before \section you will prevent one after.

Comment: Thanks John- got it. Let me try it out - will report back.

Comment: BTW, the usual solution is to put both in a minipage.  I didn't mention it since I assumed you had already tried it.

Comment: Thanks John. There's no minipage in ConTeXt, but there are [rough equivalents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77696).

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt: The equivalent of @JohnKormylo's code in ConTeXt will be `\setuphead[setion][before={\testpage[4]}]` which will check if there are at least space for `4` lines on the page; if not, it will issue a page break.

Comment: For why LaTeX and ConTeXt behave differently wrt page breaks after sections, see [this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context/33913/focus=33938). It is hard to test without a minimal example, but you can also try: `\setuphead[after={\blank[samepage]}]` or `\placefigure[force,here]` or `\placefigure[always,here]`

Comment: Thanks Aditya -- that'll definitely help get me started, which is hopefully all I need! :) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The first heading-figure splitting can be remedied by using `force` in the location parameter.  As for the second, I have found no solution and I don't think there is an easy one, because the wrapped figures mess quite a bit with how paragraphs are built and it's not easy to interact with this.

```
\starttext

\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth

\startsection[title={With a Chart}]

  \startplacefigure[location={force,here}]
    \externalfigure[Chart.pdf]
  \stopplacefigure

  \input knuth
  \input knuth
  \input knuth

\stopsection

\startsection[title={With a Chart}]

  \startplacefigure[location={force,right}]
    \externalfigure[Chart.pdf][width=5cm]
  \stopplacefigure

  Hello, world ...

\stopsection

\stoptext
```

[image]